# Android Studio vs. Eclipse IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

Google just announced the latest release of the newest Android IDE called Android Studio.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

So I was wondering, what exactly are the better features than that of Eclipse? Is it still in its early stages, is it wise to shift to the new IDE or stick with Eclipse currently?

Also, it has "**Gradle-based build support**", but Eclipse has a plug-in for it right?

Regards.

Comment: "Gradle-based build support" means it supports Gradle for building.

Comment: what is gadle based build.